# getting multiple queries with “show transaction isolation level” in pg_activity

Tags: transactions, postgresql-9.2

i am using postgres db server for my production use.

when i fire a query `select * from pg_stat_activity` on my postgresql server, 
so i getting 98% of queries like `"SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL"` and my postgresql server accepts only 100 connections.
and my server get stucked.
so i am not able to proceed further.

any one have idea why this happened, is there any idea to block this all queries.
or why this query create this many no of connections ?.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` is likely to be called when your connection pool open up a connection

Have you tried reduce your connection pool size, try set it to **1** and see, you might get a better idea on what's going on.

I just had a similar problem today which is how I found this post, I found `max connection reached` only happens in my test environment, the reason is that my test framework (ScalaTest) seems to instantiate the database object in ORM for every test case.

For example my postgres have

- `max_connections = 100`
- `connection pool = 100`

it supposed to be fine, if there's only 1 app connect to the database, however in test, the connection pool is instantiate as many as my test cases, thus it reach the maximum easily.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't nearly enough information to even start solving this in your description so what follows is general troubleshooting advice.

1. Start by looking at the other information in pg_stat_activity.  What is the application_name?  What are the IP addresses involved?  In short, where are these queries coming from?
2. If you have a shortage of connections the questions are why you are getting so many and why are they doing so little work.  This involves troubleshooting the client software not the server itself.  Also worth asking is whether the queries are active, idle, or idle in transaction, and if they are just idle, why they have not disconnected if that is a limit.

This being said, my guess is these are coming from a db framework that the client software is using to connect.  And my guess is you more likely have a db connecction leak than lots of queries doing useless stuff.